# Kill a Task with no window and space inside the Name – in Batch

Tags: batch-file, task, kill

I would like to kill a process via Batch. The problem with that is, it has now window, running in background and got a space inside the name and further it is no service.

I tried already the following

```
taskkill /F /IM Battle.net%20Helper.exe

taskkill /F /IM Battle.net% %Helper.exe

taskkill /F /IM Battle.net Helper.exe
```

and many more weird things

Comment: [http://superuser.com/q/279008/420621](http://superuser.com/q/279008/420621) This super-user question has your answer. And by the way, you're not working in "batch". You're just working on the command prompt. "Batch" is a script that executes a "batch" of commands. They usually end with ".bat" or ".cmd" extensions. Since you're really just asking how to enter commands on the command prompt, this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: As a general rule, arguments with spaces need to be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: taskkill /F /IM "Battle.net Helper.exe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In batch file you should write it like this:

```
@echo off
taskkill /F /IM "Battle.net Helper.exe"
pause
```

Comment: Oh.. allright thank you, wrapping it inside " and " did the trick :)